# Inverse Laplace transform - Getting a compact solution

Tags: integral-transforms

I had the following inverse laplace transform:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(s + Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 12])/(
 Subscript[V, 
  1] (s^2 + 
    s (Subscript[k, 1] + Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 12] + 
       Subscript[k, 21]) + Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[k, 2] + 
    Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[k, 12] + 
    Subscript[k, 2] Subscript[k, 21])), s, t]
```

The solution is:

[image]

My goal is to get a compact solution like this:

$$A exp(at) + B exp(bt)$$

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: What is V?  Did you try `FullSimplify`?

Comment: Hello @David G. Stork all k and V are positive constants. Your solution works also very good!

Comment: Never use an upper-case letter (e.g., V) for a function or variable as it may conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Collect`:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(s + Subscript[k, 2] + 
     Subscript[k, 12])/(Subscript[V, 
      1] (s^2 + 
       s (Subscript[k, 1] + Subscript[k, 2] + Subscript[k, 12] + 
          Subscript[k, 21]) + Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[k, 2] + 
       Subscript[k, 1] Subscript[k, 12] + 
       Subscript[k, 2] Subscript[k, 21])), s, t] // 
 Collect[#, Exp[__]] &
```

$\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)}-k_1+k_2+k_{12}-k_{21}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)} V_1}\times\\\exp \left[\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)}-\frac{k_1}{2}-\frac{k_2}{2}-\frac{k_{12}}{2}-\frac{k_{21}}{2}\right) t\right]+\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)}+k_1-k_2-k_{12}+k_{21}\right) }{2 \sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)} V_1} \times\\
\exp \left[\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left(k_1+k_2+k_{12}+k_{21}\right){}^2-4 \left(k_1 k_2+k_{21} k_2+k_1 k_{12}\right)}-\frac{k_1}{2}-\frac{k_2}{2}-\frac{k_{12}}{2}-\frac{k_{21}}{2}\right) t\right]$

Comment: thank you very much for your extremely clear answer!

Comment: Can you tell me what is the meaning of the last & in your code please? I know its meaning only if it is followed by another argument.

Comment: You can see that `Collect` has an `#` inside. Therefore `\\Collect[#,Exp[___]]&` does the same as `Collect[InverseLaplaceTransform[...],Exp[___]]`, i.e., take the previous result as its argument in `#`. That is why `&` should be after. It is a pure like `Function` construction

Comment: See postfix form at [`Special Ways to Input Expressions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html)